# Center text in a rhombus and make the rest of content as ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add text to a rhombus, the text should be at the center and occupy only the content between the lines.

Any excess text should have an ellipsis to the end.
The text should start flowing from the center and occupy the rest of the space.

I've written some implementation, but it's not close.

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7q4x6f9j/2/

[image]

```js
var hello = "adfadfsaf";
var textElement = document.getElementById("text1");

textElement.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("labeltext").textContent = event.target.value;
  window.localStorage.setItem("savedText", event.target.value);
});


if (window.localStorage.getItem("savedText")) {
  textElement.value = window.localStorage.getItem("savedText");

}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

#rhombus {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#labeltext {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  align-self: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="text1" />
<div id="parent">
  <div id="rhombus">
    <div class="label">
      <span id="labeltext" value=""></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't make the text force an ellipsis when it overflows vertically. [From Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow): `The text-overflow property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its inline progression direction (not text overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example).` You would have to put the 4th line into its own element with `white-space: nowrap` to get it to show the ellipsis or trim the text and add the ellipsis yourself in Javascript.

Comment: @David text overflow ellipsis is the last I want to worry about, I am more concerned about how I can center the text to take only that particular area that I mentioned and even in that particular area the text  should start from the center and flow to the rest of the content without crossing the borders.

Comment: Fix the height of the label text to whatever height you want (e.g. 4 * your line height). That will confine it to that height. Since your rhombus is rotated and then the text is rotated the opposite direction, it's rotation center point is offset, which is why a short string will be on the top right of the "rhombus". I would either separate the two elements so the rhombus is basically just an absolutely positioned background and the text doesn't have to be rotated, or you'll have to define the transform origin, but that's likely significantly more complicated.

Comment: @David thanks, regarding rhombus rotation, I've just added that as an example, I will be using :before and after psuedo selectors on the divs to rotate it so that it doesn't rotate the contents within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the ellipsis on the text you can do:

```
String.prototype.trunc = 
      function(n){
          return this.substr(0,n-1)+(this.length>n?'...':'');
      };
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById("labeltext").textContent = event.target.value.trunc(15);
```

fiddle with centered text:

https://jsfiddle.net/4yzewrk9/

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is very close to what I am expecting. Only concern is when I have an example text such as :   "ThisIsTextContent", in your fiddle the first letter is getting cropped. There are other scenarios when the text is overflowing the border, but I am not  that concerned about it now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4yzewrk9/ this is an updated fiddle, with word-break: break-all;

Answer (score 0):

You better use absolute positioning to handle this one :

```js
var textElement = document.getElementById("text1");

textElement.addEventListener("change" , (event) => {
    document.getElementById("labeltext").textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
#parent{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

#rhombus {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);  
}



#labeltext {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  height: 74px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value= "" id="text1"/>
<div id="parent">
<div id="rhombus">
  <div id="labeltext" value=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Automatic ellipsis can be handled in many ways but not with text-overflow that will only work with single line. See https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin for some hints